# Search and return single field of cloudkit records

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have cloudKit records in the format

```
KeyWords : String
Content : Asset
```

Where the assets are approx 100k.

I'm using a SearchDisplayController to query the public database but it's returning the entire record. Every tutorial I can find does this too.

Is there a way to only return the KeyWords field eg by using predicates in a certain way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK Got something working. This may well be hacky but I put it up for info for anyone else in the same situation...

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true) // returns all - replace with whatever condition you want
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Library", predicate: predicate) // create a query using the predicate
var operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query) // create an operation using the query
operation.desiredKeys = ["KeyWords"] // Array of whatever 'columns' you want to return
// operation.resultsLimit = 15 // optional limit on records

// Define a closure for what to do for each returned record
operation.recordFetchedBlock = { [weak self] (record:CKRecord!) in

    // Do whatever you want with each returned record  
    println(record.objectForKey("KeyWords"))

}

// Define a closure for when the operation is complete
operation.queryCompletionBlock = { [weak self] (cursor:CKQueryCursor!, error:NSError!) in

        if cursor != nil {
            // returns the point where the operation left off if you want t retrieve the rest of the records
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            // Do what you want when process complete
            self!.tableView.reloadData()
            if error != nil {
                println("there was an error")
            }
        })
    }

self.publicDatabase!.addOperation(operation) // Perform the operation on given database
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using CKQueryOperation to obtain your records, you can set its [desiredKeys](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQueryOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CKQueryOperation/desiredKeys) property to filter out unneeded values. Something like this.

```
fetchOperation.desiredKeys = ["KeyWords"]
```

Comment: I was using `CKQuery` which I perform with `publicDatabase?.performQuery` . Is there a parallel method for CKFetchRecordsOperation . I'm finding the documentation pretty obtuse!

Comment: @Derek No, there isn't unfortunately. You'd have to rework your code to use one of CloudKit's NSOperation subclasses which have this property.

Comment: thanks for your help. I got something working and have posted code as an answer. If you wouldn't mind casting your eye over it it would be appreciated.